# Mixed Model testing difference between groups and interpretation of assumptions?

Tags: r, mixed-model, interpretation, random-effects-model, assumptions

I am a student looking at the annual growth for a species and trying to determine if there is a difference between the growth back in time (with time divided into different time groups (30 IDs/25% of the test samples per group)) compared to a reference (recent) group. The data includes 120 test samples (with data collected for 1-50 years per sample) & 30 reference samples (with 8-10 years per sample).

It was suggested that the best method to determine if there was a significant difference between group means would be a mixed model.

I have very basic stats understanding, and am feeling very out of my depth/confused. I have spent a lot of time haunting the forum, but have reached the point where direct feedback on my stats would help my understanding immensely.

My questions:

1. Have I been given the correct advice and am I using the correct stats (mixed model) to attempt to answer my question? Or should I be using Anova or some other test?
2. Is the model I have used acceptable for the question I am asking?
3. Have I interpreted the tests for the assumption of the mixed effect model correctly? Should I be trying to transform the data (or something else) to better meet the assumptions?
4. Am I missing any assumptions to determine how valid the model is for determining between group differences?

The general data structure is:

- extn - growth measure, values between 0.9 and 2
- ID - sample ID
- sample - if it is test or reference sample
- time.group - 4 time groups (e.g. group4 = 920-800, group3 = 700-600, group2  = 550-400 & group1 = 310-200 years ago) the reference (recent) group
- location - 3 regions

Data by group looks something like this:
[image: boxplot of growth by time group and reference group on the right]

I have tried analysing the data with a very simple model using the lme4/lmertest packages as what I am primarily concerned with is whether the growth has changed between time groups and need to account for random/sample effects:

```
growth_model <- lmer(extn ~ time.group + (1|ID), data=df)
```

However, I am unsure about linearity, the normality of residuals seems to be questionable, but the homoscedasticity is passable I think if using the full dataset.

Linearity as per below:

[image: original extn values vs residual model values]

- Looks relatively random.

Normality of residuals:

[image: plot of model residuals -normality/qqplot]

[image: Distribution curve of residuals]

- Not a perfect fit. Seems to have features of a "light-tailed" distribution,but I couldn't find a method to correct for this (by transforming data or otherwise).

Homoscedasticity (and independence?) of residuals:

[image: homosecdasticity of model residuals]

- From my understanding this is acceptable and wouldn't be considered to portray non-independence or heteroscedasticity.

Thus the model results:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: extn ~ time.group + (1 | ID)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: -2297.2

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.7400 -0.5227  0.0064  0.5455  4.4974 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.022431 0.14977 
 Residual             0.003214 0.05669 
Number of obs: 984, groups:  ID, 150

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.28510    0.02756 138.95036  46.635  < 2e-16 ***
Group1      0.19094    0.03954 142.19564   4.829 3.51e-06 ***
Group2      0.22570    0.03947 141.26243   5.718 6.19e-08 ***
Group3      0.14851    0.03936 144.49191   3.773 0.000235 ***
Group4      0.26097    0.03839 143.50100   6.798 2.64e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
         (Intr) Group1 Group2 Group3
Group1 -0.697                       
Group2 -0.698  0.487                
Group3 -0.700  0.488   0.489        
Group4 -0.718  0.500   0.501   0.502
```

The results should be acceptable as there is no gross violation of assumptions visible.
Thus from the summary output the result would suggest there is likely a significant difference between each of the time groups and the reference group.

To reiterate my questions:

1. Have I been given the correct advice and am I using the correct stats (mixed model) to attempt to answer my question? Or should I be using Anova or some other test?
2. Is the model I have used acceptable for the question I am asking?
3. Have I interpreted the tests for the assumption of the mixed effect model correctly? Should I be trying to transform the data (or something else) to better meet the assumptions?
4. Am I missing any assumptions to determine how valid the model is for determining between group differences?

**EDIT**
Normality tests when extn is log transformed:
[image: log transformed extn data qqplot and residual density distribution]

```
growth_model2 <- lmer(extn ~ time.group + location + (1|ID), data=df)


Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: extn
              Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
time.group   59.935  4  2.994e-12 ***
location     30.657  2  2.202e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


         
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaites method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: extn ~ time.group + location + (1 | ID)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: -2314.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.7048 -0.5359  0.0026  0.5505  4.5311 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.018572 0.1363  
 Residual             0.003215 0.0567  
Number of obs: 984, groups:  ID, 150

Fixed effects:
           Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.36738    0.03368 138.58051  40.603  < 2e-16 ***
Group1      0.19071    0.03677 138.68803   5.186 7.45e-07 ***
Group2      0.25088    0.03631 137.83590   6.909 1.65e-10 ***
Group3      0.13435    0.03605 141.73778   3.727 0.000279 ***
Group4      0.21248    0.03663 140.95684   5.801 4.15e-08 ***
locN        -0.05306   0.03057 142.89959  -1.736 0.084788 .  
locS        -0.17783   0.03449 140.81940  -5.155 8.41e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) Group1 Group1 Group1 Group1 locN
Group1 -0.413                                     
Group2 -0.443  0.479                              
Group3 -0.544  0.479   0.473                      
Group4 -0.700  0.436   0.439   0.493              
locN   -0.612 -0.184  -0.073   0.009  0.232       
locS   -0.593 -0.070  -0.129   0.062  0.283  0.638
```

This demonstrates a significant interaction of groups using emmeans and pairs to test (truncated for main relevant pairs):

```
 contrast                          estimate     SE  df t.ratio p.value
 (Reference C) - (Group1 C)       -0.19071 0.0368 140  -5.186  0.0001
 (Reference C) - (Group2 C)       -0.25088 0.0363 139  -6.909  <.0001
 (Reference C) - (Group3 C)       -0.13435 0.0360 143  -3.727  0.0212
 (Reference C) - (Group4 C)       -0.21248 0.0366 142  -5.801  <.0001
 (Reference C) - (Reference N)     0.05306 0.0306 144   1.736  0.9183
 (Reference C) - (Reference S)     0.17783 0.0345 142   5.155  0.0001
 (Group1 C) - (Group2 C)          -0.06017 0.0373 142  -1.614  0.9530
 (Group1 C) - (Group3 C)           0.05636 0.0372 147   1.516  0.9720
 (Group1 C) - (Group4 C)          -0.02177 0.0390 146  -0.559  1.0000
 (Group2 C) - (Group3 C)           0.11653 0.0371 145   3.139  0.1183
 (Group2 C) - (Group4 C)           0.03840 0.0386 144   0.994  0.9996
 (Group3 C) - (Group4 C)          -0.07813 0.0366 148  -2.134  0.7098
 (Reference N) - (Group1 N)       -0.19071 0.0368 140  -5.186  0.0001
 (Reference N) - (Group2 N)       -0.25088 0.0363 139  -6.909  <.0001
 (Reference N) - (Group3 N)       -0.13435 0.0360 143  -3.727  0.0212
 (Reference N) - (Group4 N)       -0.21248 0.0366 142  -5.801  <.0001
 (Reference N) - (Reference S)     0.12477 0.0279 142   4.472  0.0014
 (Group1 N) - (Group2 N)          -0.06017 0.0373 142  -1.614  0.9530
 (Group1 N) - (Group3 N)           0.05636 0.0372 147   1.516  0.9720
 (Group1 N) - (Group4 N)          -0.02177 0.0390 146  -0.559  1.0000
 (Group2 N) - (Group3 N)           0.11653 0.0371 145   3.139  0.1183
 (Group2 N) - (Group4 N)           0.03840 0.0386 144   0.994  0.9996
 (Group3 N) - (Group4 N)          -0.07813 0.0366 148  -2.134  0.7098
 (Reference S) - (Group1 S)       -0.19071 0.0368 140  -5.186  0.0001
 (Reference S) - (Group2 S)       -0.25088 0.0363 139  -6.909  <.0001
 (Reference S) - (Group3 S)       -0.13435 0.0360 143  -3.727  0.0212
 (Reference S) - (Group4 S)       -0.21248 0.0366 142  -5.801  <.0001
 (Group1 S) - (Group2 S)          -0.06017 0.0373 142  -1.614  0.9530
 (Group1 S) - (Group3 S)           0.05636 0.0372 147   1.516  0.9720
 (Group1 S) - (Group4 S)          -0.02177 0.0390 146  -0.559  1.0000
 (Group2 S) - (Group3 S)           0.11653 0.0371 145   3.139  0.1183
 (Group2 S) - (Group4 S)           0.03840 0.0386 144   0.994  0.9996
 (Group3 S) - (Group4 S)          -0.07813 0.0366 148  -2.134  0.7098
```

Comment: The description of your data is not clear, at least to me, partly because you talk of "sample groups" and "time groups". Perhaps drop the generic term "groups" and describe -- both for a reference sample and for a test sample -- how many growth measurements you have and at what time periods. It would be helpful to include some data as well.

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks for your suggestions. I have made some edits to the original post, which hopefully clarify things slightly. I don't believe I am allowed to share the exact data at this time, but could re-scale the data. Would that be useful or muddle the issue? I am trying to tell if there has been a change in growth pattern more generally and thus I'm making a comparison of the group means.

Comment: It is a challenge when looking back in time since it is impossible to gather data like-for-like and the samples from the time group 4 which is say 500 years ago are those available with usable data to compare to the reference (recent) growth.

Comment: Otherwise the model seems reasonable (though I can see why you ask about the fit). Perhaps you can consider log-transforming growth or using a generalized linear model (*glmer*) with log link. And do you have more precise estimate of time (which has then been binned into groups)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, hopefully I have improved my explanation of the context. According to my field they are ordered by time (oldest group4 on left/bottom and youngest reference on right/bottom).

Comment: I tried log-transforming the data, but to my (inexperienced) eye this appears to be similar or slightly further from a normal distribution than the original data (I have edited the original to include the normality tests for the log transformed growth data). The log transformed data does have a notably smaller AIC value compared to the original data(logAIC= -4621, origAIC= -2335), although I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: I do not understand glmer format enough seemingly. Every attempt I have tried throws errors about eigenvalue large ratio and questioning re-scaling the data, but any and all attempt I have made at re-scaling the data ends with further errors.

Comment: I have added location to the model (with + as I don't believe it is a * interaction, but I may very well be wrong) and I've edited my original post to include the model results (Anova & truncated emmeans with pairs results). This shows many notable significant interactions, but is any of that meaningful with the assumption test results as shown above?

Comment: It's hard to understand the model without the data and you have really explained the structure of the data yet. So a couple of final comments: a) You cannot use AIC to compare a model for Y and a model for a transformation f(Y). So it makes sense to stick with Y = growth. b) You don't explain how *time.group*s are clustered with *ID*s, so not clear what the *glmer* messages are about. (This could a question on its own?)

Comment: c) It's obvious from the box plot that the groups have different growth and it's not surprising the growth 800 ago is not the same as growth 400 ago, etc. These are the comparisons you are making right now. It's up to you to decide if these contrasts actually answer your research question. Finally, I suggest that you split this analysis is smaller steps and tackle them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and suggestions. The information has been helpful in directing some of my stats research. Definitely hamstrung by being unable to share the original data.

Comment: There is the option to simulate data. Though of course simulating data that has the same patterns we want to study in the real data is often non-trivial.